# constructor does not run

Tags: c++, constructor, most-vexing-parse

I do not understand because when you create an object of the "Users" class not the message is printed containing the constructor.

```
class users
{
public:
    users();
private:
    int i;
};
users::users ()
{
    cout<<"hello world";
}
int main ()
{
    users users1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't creating "an object of the `users` class".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: Google "bdfl".  C++ needs one.

Comment: You may also need to output `\n` or `<< endl` to see the output

Comment: @MattMcNabb : Standard streams are guaranteed in the standard to be flushed before destruction.

Answer (score 3):

```
users users1();
```

doesn't declare an object of the `users` class, it declares a function that takes no arguments and returns an object of the `users` class. To declare an object, use:

```
users users1;
```

Comment: or `users users1{};`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class users
{
public:
    users();
private:
    int i;
};
users::users ()
{
    cout<<"hello world";
}
int main ()
{
    users users1; // either you use this
    users* user2 = new users(); // or you do this
    return 0;
}
```

This worked fine for me. see [here](http://ideone.com/vKFxiv)